# If-else block in nested for loops - Compiler claims I need a return statement

Tags: java, boolean

How do I make this work? It says that I need to add a return statement but I have one.

```
public boolean clockFactCheck(int a, int b){
    for (int i = 0; i <= 276; i++){
        for (int h = 0; h <= 55; h++){
            if (a == i + 186 && b == h + 133){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your real code? Or are you just messing with the compiler? Those loops never iterate, always returning with `i==h==0`, right?

Comment: If it compiled, that could would only execute the body of the the loops once, and then return, since the innermost loop body is an `if` where both branches return out of the function. There would be no second iteration. You may as well ditch the loops and write `return a == 186 && b == 133;`

Comment: [The compiler is not infinitely clever](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/24/never-say-never-part-two.aspx) - it's about C#, but it's very applicable here

Comment: @SWeko It has nothing to do with cleverness - compiler behaviour is fully defined by the language specification.

Comment: @assylias - My point exactly. Even if a human could deduce that this method will always return, the compiler does not try such deduction.

Comment: This isn't all my code this is just a small section. I asked the question because I didn't understand why this would recieve an error when it always reaches a return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code provided may not reach one of the `return`s for any input `a,b` and that's what the compiler is complaining about.

Actually in your case the `if-else` will be reached with the very first iteration - unfortunately something which the compiler cannot deduce. Therefore, it goes the save way and issues this error.

*Comment:* Therefore, in your loop seems not to make much sense since it will not iterate at all but stop within the first iteration `i==0` and `h==0`. Did you meant to code something like that?

Comment: Why? For any a and b, one of the returns will be reached.

Comment: The whole method is equivalent to `return (a == 0 + 186 && b == 0 + 133);`.

Comment: @assylias You're right, just read the code wrong the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a return statement after the for loop but even then h++ is dead code becaue it will never get past the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Place the return statement outside the loop. (declare a boolean in your function, modify it and return it at the end)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the compiler is not clever enough to figure out that there is no codepath around the loops.

If this is real code, simplify it to

```
return (a == 186 && b == 133);
```

If this is not the real code, there is probably another path that does not return (if you made an error pasting), or there really is a compiler bug or limitation. At one point, the halting problem bites you, and the code is too complex for the compiler to figure out.

In the latter case I would place a

```
throw new RuntimeException(
   String.format("should never get here (a = %d, b = %d) !",a,b));
```

at the last statement.

That makes both the compiler happy and does not introduce an "undefined" return value for a case that should either never happen, or if it does, has not been thought of.

Answer (score 0):

Java requires every path return a value. The compiler could not judge if the circulation will return a path. If your code is like this:

```
public boolean add(){
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    if(i==5000)
    return true;}
```

the function add will not return a value. Instead, an error will occur.

Answer (score 0):

Oh yeah my bad, I'm sorry this was a stupid question it was 5am when I posted this. I figured out the answer to my problem. If you made the same stupid mistake as me here is the fix

```
public boolean clockFactCheck(int a, int b){
    for (int i = 0; i <= 276; i++){
        for (int h = 0; h <= 55; h++){
            if (a == i + 186 && b == h + 133){
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```